# jquery displays html response on all div classes instead of only div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i know similar questions have been previously asked, but none suits my need.
i have an XHR ajax return that i want to place on the respect div class in a php loop, the ajax call was successful, but when i used jquery to replace my div class html with the ajax return on the div, it replaces all the divs in the loop. please what am i doing wrong:

My php code for the loop is as follow;

```
public function getComments() {
     try{
         $user_data = @$_SESSION['user'];
         $userid = $user_data['userid'];
         $name = $user_data['name'];
         $con = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->serverhost;dbname=starstv;" , $this->serverusername, $this->serverpassword);
         $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
         $fetch_p_comment = $con -> prepare("SELECT parent_comments.name,parent_comments.likes,parent_comments.dislikes,parent_comments.comment,users.profile_pics,parent_comments.comment_time,parent_comments.code FROM parent_comments INNER JOIN users ON parent_comments.name = users.name ORDER BY comment_time DESC");
         $fetch_p_comment -> execute();
         $p = $fetch_p_comment -> fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

         foreach($p as $item) {
            $item[] = $p;
            $date = new dateTime($item['comment_time']);
            $comment_time = date_format($date, 'M j, Y | H:i:s');
            $name = $item['name'];
            $comment = $item['comment'];
            $par_code = $item['code'];
            $user_image = $item['profile_pics'];
            $likes = $item['likes'];
            $dislikes = $item['dislikes'];
               echo '<div id="parent-comment"></div>';
            echo "<div class='comment' id='parent' name='".$par_code."'>"
                ."<img src='".$user_image."' alt='profile image'>"
                ."<span class='user' id ='name'>".$name."</span>"
                ."<span class='time'>".$comment_time."</span>"
                .'<div class="comment-text"><p class="position-comments">'.$comment.'</p></div>'
                ."<img src='images/like.jpg' class='likes-mama' name=".$par_code." id='okay'><span class='likes-mama-updates' id='ccc-likes'>&nbsp;".$likes."</span><img src='images/dislike.jpg' class='dislikes-mama' id='okay' name=".$par_code."><span class='dislikes-mama-updates' id='ccc-dislikes'>&nbsp;".$dislikes."</span><br>"
                ."<a class='link-reply' id='reply' name='".$par_code."' value='".$par_code."' title='reply comment'>reply</a> <a class='edit-comment' id='edit' name='".$par_code."' value='".$par_code."' title='you can only edit your comment'>edit</a> <a class='delete-comment' id='delete' name='".$par_code."' value='".$par_code."'title='you can only delete your comment'>delete</a><br><br>";                               
            $fetch_c_reply = $con -> prepare("SELECT children_comments.name,children_comments.likes,children_comments.dislikes,children_comments.comment,users.profile_pics,children_comments.comment_time,children_comments.par_code FROM children_comments INNER JOIN users ON children_comments.name = users.name WHERE children_comments.par_code =? ORDER BY comment_time DESC");
            $fetch_c_reply -> bindParam(1,$par_code);
            if($fetch_c_reply -> execute()) {
            $c = $fetch_c_reply -> fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $c_count = $fetch_c_reply->rowCount();

            if($c_count == 0) {
                // do nothing
            }else {
                echo "<a class='link-reply' id='children' name='".$par_code."'><img src='images/images(39).jpg' alt='' id='kiop' title='toggle to see replies'>(".$c_count.")&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='images/images(39).jpg' alt='' id='kioper' title='toggle to see replies'><div id='form-ajax'></div></a>"
                    ."<div class='child-comments' id='C-".$par_code."'>";
                    foreach($c as $com) {
                        $com[] = $c;
                        $c_date = new dateTime($com['comment_time']);
                        $c_comment_time = date_format($c_date, 'M j, Y | H:i:s');
                        $c_name = $com['name'];
                        $c_comment = $com['comment'];
                        $c_par = $com['par_code'];
                        $image = $com['profile_pics'];
                        $likes = $com['likes'];
                        $dislikes = $com['dislikes'];


                        echo '<div id="parent-comment"></div>';
                        echo "<div class='child' id='".$par_code."-C' value='".$par_code."'>"
                        ."<img src='".$image."' alt='profile image'>"
                        ."<span class='user'>".$c_name."</span>"
                        ."<span class='time'>".$c_comment_time."</span>"
                        ."<div class='comment-text'><p class='position-comments'>".$c_comment."</p></div>"
                        ."<img src='images/like.jpg' class='c-likes' name=".$par_code." value=".$c_comment." id='okay'><span >&nbsp;".$likes."</span><img src='images/dislike.jpg' class='c-dislikes' id='okay' value=".$c_comment." name=".$par_code." ><span >&nbsp;".$dislikes."</span><br>"
                        ."<div></div>"
                        ."</div>";
                    }
                    echo  "</div>";
                }

            }
            echo "</div>";
         }

        }catch(PDOException $e) {
         throw new PDOException($e->getMessage());
     }
 }
```

that's the complete php code returning the loop;

the php loop code is below;

```
echo "<div class='comment' id='parent' name='".$par_code."'>"
                ."<img src='".$user_image."' alt='profile image'>"
                ."<span class='user' id ='name'>".$name."</span>"
                ."<span class='time'>".$comment_time."</span>"
                .'<div class="comment-text"><p class="position-comments">'.$comment.'</p></div>'
                ."<img src='images/like.jpg' class='likes-mama' name=".$par_code." id='okay' ><span class='likes-mama-updates' id='ccc-likes'>&nbsp;".$likes."</span><img src='images/dislike.jpg' class='dislikes-mama' id='okay' name=".$par_code."><span class='dislikes-mama-updates' id='ccc-dislikes'>&nbsp;".$dislikes."</span><br>"
                ."<a class='link-reply' id='reply' name='".$par_code."' value='".$par_code."' title='reply comment'>reply</a> <a class='edit-comment' id='edit' name='".$par_code."' value='".$par_code."' title='you can only edit your comment'>edit</a> <a class='delete-comment' id='delete' name='".$par_code."' value='".$par_code."' title='you can only delete your comment'>delete</a></div>";
```

my javascript code is below;

```
$(".likes-mama").one('click', function() {
                        var p_comment_likes = true;
                        var gCode = $(this).attr("name");

                        if(gCode != "" && p_comment_likes ==true) {

                            var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                            hr.open("POST","p_comment_likes_dislikes.php",true);
                            hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                            hr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                                if((hr.readyState == 4) && (hr.status == 200 || hr.status == 304) ) {
                                    $(".likes-mama-updates").html(hr.response);
                                    alert(hr.response);
                                }
                            }
                            hr.send("code="+gCode+"&p_comment_likes="+p_comment_likes);
                        }
                  });
```

please your replies are appreciated

Comment: You're putting the requested PHP output into every element that has `class="likes-mama-updates"`. I don't think that's what you want, I can't be sure though because your code is almost unreadable. You should at the very least remove all those inline styles. You're also echoing `id="..."` inside a loop, which means you'll have tons of elements with the same supposedly unique `id`.

Comment: please make this more readable.

Comment: ok let me edit the code more

Comment: @ChrisG, i have removed the inline styles and also, that thing you called id is a code i used to identify each loop. As it is now, please how can i use jquery to drop my ajax return each span element of the class= "likes-mama-updates" whenever the images tag is clicked as shown in my code

Comment: Go read https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/ and find out which methods might be suitable to select the correct span element based on its position in the DOM in relation to the currently clicked image.

Comment: the php code of interest is the small php loop code not all the php code that i included for further clarification of my code

Comment: @CBroe i justread your article, but couldn't find help their, the ajax response replaces all loop class whether it is a span element or a div element that is used. Please does it mean that jquery cannot select the only one div or span element that is clicked and drop the required response, i really need help here pls.

Comment: _“does it mean that jquery cannot select the only one div or span element that is clicked”_ - no, it just means _you_ have to be more explicit in what you are instructing jQuery to select in the first place ... The click happens on a `.likes-mama` element, that is your `$(this)` inside the handler function. So now all you got to do is select only the `.likes-mama-updates` element that immediately follows the image - for example via a simple https://api.jquery.com/next/ call.

Comment: please @CBroe, can you iiustrate using code, i do notreally understand what you mean? how do i select only the .likes-mama-updates class that is clicked in .likes-mama parent class, explain more

Comment: `$(this)` refers to the image the user clicked on, so call the next method on that object ...

Comment: i have don all of that even as described by the jquery api, this time it doesnt even append the ajax response on any div again

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of work around, i was able to find the solution with parent-children relationship in jquery:

```
$(this).parent().children("my-class");
```

to locate the actual div i want.
thanks all for your quick response!!